# Pipe | operator does not work in MySQL ( phpmyadmin) with Heidi SQL Database

Tags: mysql

So I have a chatapp in Php with a database in mySQL phpmyadmin, for the table Chatbot I have 3 columns Id , queries & replies, when I store a value in queries such as `Hey|Hello` & in replies such as `Hello|Hi` & then I try the app by writing `Hey`, the reply is returned as `Hello|Hi`.

What I want in each cell in replies & queries to have multiple values so each time I write `Hello` or any other argument, I should get the corresponding reply.

The question is, is it possible to store more values in a cell in mysql with an this OR that argument? [database column screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcaAf.jpg)

Both the queries & replies are `varchar` elements with a maximum length of 300 characters

Comment: okay Thanks , can you point me how best to store dialogue data for a chatbot in mysql , lets say I have dialogues such as 
Queries: How are you ? or Whats up ? or How is it going ? 
how do I match all this different queries to standard replies such as I am good, I am alright etc.
Should I store each argument as a separate row ?
I have a large Json Intents file (dialogues) that I wish to incorporate , it would be tough to have an individual row for each chat senetnce/word/argument ? Thanks

Comment: For example this Json array
{"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["Hi there", "How are you", "Is anyone there?","Hey","Hola", "Hello", "Good day", "Moin", "Anybody Home"],
     "responses": ["Hello, thanks for asking", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?", "Moin", "Yes, my name is Borat and this is the help desk. How can I help you today?"]
how can I import this in mysql so each comma separated value is stored in a separate row in respective columns ?

Comment: Replies are directly related to Queries , the consequence of a query is a reply.
in Json array above Hi There is a pattern of a query & responses are responses
& HI There should stand for Hi ,Hello, Good Morning , Hey , Whats up etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes can store more values in a cell . but sql will be considered as one value

SO you will get as single sting from Chatbot table .

Because SQL has atomic value in each cell.

ACID refers to the four key properties of a transaction: atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability.

You should create separate tables for queries & replies.